# Automatic solution for nice roots - but problem with nested ones

Tags: math-mode

Please look at the following MWE. I found an automatic solution for nice roots. The depth of letters ist ignored and subscripts do not influence the depth.

But when I nest the roots, it gets ugly. What am I doing wrong? What has to be done for nice nested roots?

Thanks.

Sorry for using `\over`, but I usually use Plain (Lua-)TeX. But loading OTF fonts with low level commands would give many extra lines in the code, so I write this MWE with LuaLaTeX and Unicode Math.

```
% Only for LuaTeX
\documentclass[17pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newbox\r@@tbox
\newdimen\r@dic@ldepth

% to get cramped style
\def\mathpalettecramped#1#2{\mathchoice{#1\crampeddisplaystyle{#2}}%
    {#1\crampedtextstyle{#2}}{#1\crampedscriptstyle{#2}}%
    {#1\crampedscriptscriptstyle{#2}}}

\protected\def\sqrt{\mathpalettecramped\printr@@t}

\def\printr@@t#1#2{\begingroup
    \Umathcodenum`j=`i % example for goobling depth of letters
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\scantokens{\catcode`\_=\active \let_=\@gobble
                    $\m@th#1{\vphantom{0}#2}$}} % Subscripts do not influence depth
    \global\r@dic@ldepth\dp\z@
    \endgroup
    \setbox\r@@tbox\hbox{$\m@th#1{\vphantom{0}#2}$}
    \dp\r@@tbox\r@dic@ldepth
    \Uradical"0"221A {\box\r@@tbox}}

\section{Good}
This works fine for not nested roots:
$ \sqrt A \sqrt j $, $ \sqrt{Aj} $, $ \sqrt{1_{1_1}\over Aj_{A_A}} $

\section{Bad}
However, there is a problem with nested roots:
$ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{11}}}}} $

The base of the root signs alternates and the radical rules
are vertically spaced unequal. What am I doing wrong?

\end{document}
```

Comment: ` \global\` looks suspicious in anything that can be nested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you avoid the global setting with

```
\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\r@dic@ldepth\the\dp\z@\relax
```

Then you get

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I'm putting this question in my favorites. Why does this happen with root boxes? I've also tried mtpro2[lite] and the same thing happens.

Comment: @Sebastiano it's nothing to do with roots, as I commented under the question anything using `\global` is likely to fail in a nested context as global definitions do not obey the nested scope.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. On this website I have already learned more about TeX than in every book.